# delivery address is not adding in pdf invoice in prestashop

Tags: php, pdf, prestashop-1.6

Delivery address is not adding in pdf invoice in prestashop.

I create a store on prestashop, but in its pdf invoice delivery address is missing.

How can i add the delivery address in the pdf invoice?

Please help me to fix this problem.

```
<!-- invoicing -->
<tr>
    <td colspan="12">
          {$addresses_tab}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Was your issue solved?  If yes, would be great if you could select the accepted answer so this doesn't show up as un-answered and others can learn from it too. Or if you are still after an answer, just reply and will look at helping. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

The delivery address block does not show if delivery address is same as invoice address.

If you want to display this block you can edit the template file `invoice.tpl`
and replace :

```
{if !empty($delivery_address)}
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Delivery Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$delivery_address}
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Billing Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$invoice_address}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
{else}
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>

                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Billing & Delivery Address.' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$invoice_address}
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
{/if}
```

with

```
{if !empty($delivery_address)}
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Delivery Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$delivery_address}
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Billing Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$invoice_address}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            {else}
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Delivery Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$invoice_address}
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; color: #9E9F9E">{l s='Billing Address' pdf='true'}</span><br />
                             {$invoice_address}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            {/if}
```

Comment: sir i made change in tpl file but still address are not showing in the pdf reciept. I am sending you a image file in next answer my output is look like  that one file...

Comment: Can you send me your file [themes]/[your_theme]/pdf/invoice.tpl?

Comment: there are no tpl file in that folder. i found my tpl files in public_html/pdf only

Comment: you can download invoice.tpl file from the following link https://www.sendspace.com/file/h7wat5

Comment: Ok you have the last  version of Prestashop 1.6.1.4, can you let me know the file pdf/invoice.addresses-tab.tpl?

Comment: ya sure sir https://www.sendspace.com/file/hoof4s this is the link for that file. I think $delivery_address and $invoice_address both are null...

Comment: i selected invoice-b2b in invoice model and its tpl file in the following link https://www.sendspace.com/file/nsfyho sorry for inconvenience...

Comment: mmm, can you let me know example of pdf file generated?

Comment: sir i caught the exact problem the delivery address is not send to shopname/order?step=1 from shopname/order?step=0  while checkout. but i can't find the solution plz help ...